# uniform continuity of a function in a metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A\neq\emptyset$ be a given subset of a metric space $(X,d).$ If $f(x)=d(x,A)$ show that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

Comment: Try $\delta = \epsilon/2$ for your $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, and use the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for any $z \in A$, $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y) + d(y,z) $ so that $d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z)$
taking the infimun over z yields $d(x,A)-d(y,A)\leq d(x,y)$ exchanging x and y in the above you get the inequality $d(y,A)-d(x,A)\leq d(x,y)$ so that $|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\leq d(x,y)$ thus for any $\epsilon>0$ take $\eta = \epsilon$ and you have that for any $x,y$ such that $d(x,y)<\eta$,  $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq d(x,y) <\epsilon$